# Restrict access to rows based on values and user identity in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how do I restrict access to certain rows (hide data) in tables based on the users identity?
Thanks

Comment: You will need to wait for Postgres 9.5 (currently in Beta) which supports row level security: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createpolicy.html

Comment: I have no idea why this is being downvoted into oblivion.

Answer (score 1):

[PostgreSQL 9.5 adds row-level security](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createpolicy.html), which is a built-in way to do what you want.

You can emulate it in older versions using views. `SECURITY BARRIER` views are updatable in PostgreSQL 9.4, so you can create a view over the table you want where the view predicate applies the row access restriction. Deny access to the underlying table to users and grant access to the view. They will now have to perform all access to the table through the view, which has a filter that restricts what they can see.

In 9.3 and older you can't use `SECURITY BARRIER` on a view and still have it updatable. You can still use views, but it's leakier; users who can write PL/PgSQL functions can easily expose data they aren't supposed to see, and it may be possible using only built-in functions too.